# Jenv is not picking up the system installed java

Tags: java, maven, jenv

I have jenv installed. The output of `which java` was initially `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`. I issues the following commands:

```
jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
eval "$(jenv init -)"
```

Now, the output of `which java` is

```
/Users/my_username/.jenv/shims/java
```

The output of `java -version` is the same before and after. However, `mvn clean install` is throwing error:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /Users/my_username/.jenv/versions/system/bin/java
```

Why is maven not picking up the proper java?

Comment: Can you echo $JAVA_HOME on the terminal? Does it point to a valid location?

Comment: Can you run java directly from console?

Comment: $JAVA_HOME is empty. I am able to run java -version.

Comment: Have you tried the `$ jenv enable-plugins maven` and 
`$ jenv enable-plugins export`?

Comment: I am getting "jenv: no such command `enable-plugins'" as the message when I tried to enable maven plugin.

Comment: Perhaps restart your terminal?

Comment: Restarting the terminal has the same problem

Comment: add this to .bashrc or .zshrc `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` and restart terminal, you can check first does it works by executing above command on terminal then update files.

Comment: @dkb Near as I can tell, setting `JAVA_HOME` in bashrc _seems_ help `jenv` establish where to find the system default; without that some things just don't work.  `jenv global system && java -version` works fine; but a play build didn't like it at all; it worked just fine with `jenv global system` if I had JAVA_HOME set in bashrc.

Comment: @J_D it's "`jenv enable-plugin`", not "enable-plugin**s**"

Answer (score 10):

According to documentation `eval "$(jenv init -)"` should print to console some command which you need to execute (they suggest to add them to .bash_profile).

Comment: @PapaStan Yes. And those commands produce new commands. Here is instruction on how to install from manual `echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: The documentation says that jenv init enables shims and autocompletion.

Comment: @PapaStan maybe it inits JAVA_HOME too?

Comment: @dknight no. It shows what else you have to do to make it work. You have to put those commands in your init scripts.

Comment: good info, but does not address the root problem.

Comment: @RichardSitze you mean executing command printed by `eval "$(jenv init -)"` doesn't work?

Comment: @Talex Not in my situation.  Still trying to wrap my head around my particular root-cause.  Basically, of `java` isn't on `PATH` (not including `jenv` shims) then it cannot find a system/default `java` to run, and I get the "We cannot execute /Users/my_username/.jenv/versions/system/bin/java" error described by OP.  The jenv init/setup in itself doesn't "fix" an underlying problem.  The jenv docs do not really call out how the default is determined, so I started digging into the jenv impl to work things out.

Comment: This seemed to fix my issues when adding new JAVA versions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`jenv versions` showed the current version was system. I am not sure why that version was not proper. I set the global version to `1.8.0.121` and everything is working as expected.

Comment: It is probably because you should add after init

Comment: This moves away from the system default; it does not address the root of the problem.  But it does provide a work around.